jest ReferenceError: Cannot access 'BsNavbarDropdownComponent' before initialization
I'm trying to convert my angular app (NX monorepo) to use standalone components. However when doing so, my Jest unit tests stop working and give the following error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'BsNavbarDropdownComponent' before initialization

After a lot of troubleshooting it seems to boil down to the following:
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsNavbarModule } from '@mintplayer/ng-bootstrap/navbar';
// import { BsNavbarModule } from './navbar/navbar.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'video-player-root',
  template: `<h1>ng-video-player</h1>`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BsNavbarModule]
})
export class AppComponent {}

app.component.spec.ts
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppComponent],
      declarations: [],
      providers: []
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

I copied over the entire BsNavbarModule from my library to the application. Here's a minimal reproduction. When the following is used
import { BsNavbarModule } from '@mintplayer/ng-bootstrap/navbar';

the unit test fails with
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'BsNavbarDropdownComponent' before initialization

However when the exact same, in-app module is used
import { BsNavbarModule } from './navbar/navbar.module';

the test runs perfectly fine. Why is that? How do I fix this? I've seen tons of questions with similar error message, but not mentioning jest.

Have you added the transform and moduleFileExtensions in jest.config?

UPDATE:
Could you try updating the constructor of the below file with forwardRef, this will get rid of the error.
mintplayer-ng-bootstrap\libs\mintplayer-ng-bootstrap\navbar\src\navbar-item\navbar-item.component.ts
export class BsNavbarItemComponent implements AfterContentChecked {

  constructor(
    private navbar: BsNavbarComponent,
    element: ElementRef,
    private destroy: DestroyRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    @Optional() 
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => BsNavbarDropdownComponent))  // <- changed here!
          parentDropdown: BsNavbarDropdownComponent,
  ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.parentDropdown = parentDropdown;

  }

Github Repo

nx run video-player-demo:test --testFile=apps/video-player-demo/src/app/app.component.spec.ts


Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I updated the ng-bootstrap version, and used this version in my other application. I rebased both branches (branch 1 / branch 2 ..

And I'm still getting the same error...

@Pieterjan I just wanted the change to be made only for mintplayer-ng-bootstrap not for the other dependencies, could you revert the code back to its original state, except for the single line change on mintplayer-ng-bootstrap will recheck and get back to you with a proper fix

@Pieterjan Just the above update changes needed, you can ignore the emitDecoratorMetadata part.

You sir are a savior!! I can't believe I looked over that. The circular dependency without forwardRef was the culprit

@Pieterjan Thanks nice project very structured implementation :)
